# Get status of the run for custom status update in Protractor tests

Tags: protractor

I am trying to get the test execution status as pass and fail in general for Protractor test. So that I can send that status to update the cross-browser integration tool. I could not find a better way to get the status. Help much appreciated. My function is similar to this. Want to pass 'status' as of pass or fail

```
      onComplete: function() {
        //set the score as passing
        browser.call(setScore, null, 'pass').then(function(result){
        console.log('set score to pass')
        });


      //Call API to set the score
      function setScore(score) {

       //webdriver has built-in promise to use
      var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
      var result = { error: false, message: null }

      if (sessionId){

      request({
      method: 'PUT',
      uri: 'https://crossbrowsertesting.com/api/v3/selenium/' + sessionId,
      body: {'action': 'set_score', 'score': score },
      json: true
         },).auth("tester1.code@gmail.com", "Password1!");
      }else{
      result.error = true;
      result.message = 'Session Id was not defined';
      deferred.fulfill(result);
       }
  return deferred.promise;
   }
},
```

Comment: please, use native Promise ES6

Comment: @Oleksii , thanks for the reply. Can u pls give an example ?